# PostgreSQL 8 - Substituir a primeira ocorrência de um caracter numa string

Tags: postgresql

Tenho um campo numa tabela num banco de dados PostgreSQL 8 cujos valores são strings e possuem hifens em algumas posições irregulares.

Gostaria de substituir a primeira ocorrência do hífen na string por um espaço em branco, mas não consegui achar nada apropriado na [documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-string.html).

As funções que eu achei como [REPLACE()](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-replace/) substituem todas as ocorrências e não apenas a primeira como eu desejaria.

Atualmente eu estou exportanto os resultados .CSV e abrindo no MS Excel. Com a função `=SUBSTITUIR(A1;"-";" ";1)`, eu consigo fazer isso. Mas eu busco ser mais eficiente e perco tempo fazendo isso.

Agradeço a ajuda da comunidade antecipadamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `Position` para encontrar a primeira ocorrência do hífen na sua string. Depois disso, pode substituir pelo espaço, usando a função `Overlay`:

```
select overlay('Palavra-Teste-X' placing ' ' from position('-' in 'Palavra-Teste-X') for 1)
```

> Resultado: `Palavra Teste-X`

Coloquei no **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/25f58/4)**

Documentação: **[String Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-string.html)**

Comment: Obrigado, Rovann! Sua solução resolveu meu problema. Infelizmente eu não consigo votar na resposta ainda, mas assim que puder vou dar um +1 pra ela.

Comment: Blz @Eduardo, disponha =]

Answer (score 1):

## Diretamente no SQL para POSTGRESQL 8.1+

Use a função [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

Exemplo para o seu caso

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('ALGUMA COISA - OUTRA COISA', '^([^-]*)-(.*?)', E'\\2|\\1', 'g');
-- Retorna  OUTRA COISA|ALGUMA COISA 
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('ALGUMA COISA - OUTRA COISA - MAIS OUTRA COISA', '^([^-]*)-(.*?)', E'\\1 \\2', 'g');
-- Retorna
```

Para versões anteriores é possível usar `overlay` ou `substring` conforme a resposta aceita.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta. Essa opção não está executando na versão 8 do PostgreSQL. A versão do @Rovann Linhalis resolveu meu problema. Muito obrigado mesmo!

Comment: Esta função esta disponível para PG a partir de 8.1.

Answer (score -1):

A versão 8.0 deixou de ser suportada em Outubro/2010.
Atualize sua instalação para uma versão mais recente.
A versão atual é a 10.3 que receberá suporte até Outubro/2022.